# Which way to go - MVC REST or WCF REST?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, rest

I have a set of web methods that I am planning to convert to REST on top of MVC or WCF.
But I am little confused after reading few questions and answer on similar topic.

```
** My app is .NET 4, C# with Mongo database as backend which emits JSON **
```

Here is my use cases:

- Persisting web form data (new user signs up, I need to save web form) & 
  show update status (success or failure)
- User posts a new comment/reply. I need to save the comment in DB (async w/ jquery) & 
  show update status (success or failure)
- User likes comment/reply. I need to save the like in DB (async w/ jquery) & 
  show update status (success or failure)
- User updates title, tag or any other field. I need to update DB (async w/ jquery) 
  & show the update status to the user
- User wants to view the next page of comments. I call web service and silently append 
  the comments.
- In future I paln to open the API to other apps to talk to my app. So I need REST api to 
  handle that.
- I am new to both MVC and WCF framework. So I need to learn either way I go.
  But I would prefer easy and clean coding
- Looking for light weight & faster solution (cheaper in the long run)

  Please let me know if I have to specify anything else that might clarify my need.

  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are writing a web application - I would go with MVC. You then get the testability benefits of MVC along with its inherent RESTfulness.

Tasks such as:
"Persisting web form data (new user signs up, I need to save web form) & show update status (success or failure)"

sure you can have a web app call a service to do this - but when you can get the web app and the call to do this all in a RESTful interface all inside of MVC - why go elsewhere? Rememeber - this stack overflow application is written in MVC : )

Comment: Based on, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530880/why-use-asp-net-mvc-2-for-rest-services-why-not-wcf it seems MVC might be my way. I am also looking at OpenRasta. So it will be either MVC or OpenRasta

Comment: If this was strictly for a service oriented architecture then WCF would make more sense - but the fact you are coupling this with a web app is a slam dunk.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it depends on your timeframe.  If you need to put something into production within the next 3-6 months and your API is not going to be too large, and will stick to HTML/JSON then MVC will probably do you fine.

If this is a long term strategic project then I would keep an eye on http://wcf.codeplex.com. There is some excellent new stuff coming out of the WCF group for building sophisticated web apis.

Comment: It is a long term strategy. How costly would it be to switch over to WCF from MVC later on? I have recoding, it is painful since I am going through some other pieces in the site.

Comment: no need to switch over - go with MVC and you will have all you need. the restful interface is already there. unless you need certain advanced binding characteristics with wcf (extended security, etc) or strictly a SOA not riding on a web app as well - stick with MVC

Comment: I saw some people mentioning about OpenRasta providing lot more functionality OOB. How about its performance and anyone using it on production environment?

Comment: @Projapati As long as your API is not too large it should be relatively easy to switch over.  It's all HTTP in the end.  Also, MVC and WCF Web APIs can run together as a hybrid solution.

Comment: @Adam  WCF Web APIs have quite a bit more functionality when it comes to dealing with multiple different media types, like content negotiation and formatters.  WCF Web APIs don't use any of the SOAP related extensions.

Comment: Darren I'm just missing the context in regards to this - can you explain a bit more? Content negotiation isn't very RESTful - as per it's originator (Roy Fielding)

Comment: @Adam Content negotiation is perfectly RESTful.  It's use is documented in RFC2616

Comment: still just curious why it was mentioned here - not to sound doubtful.. but I can learn something from this here maybe. can you elaborate a bit? Being http compliant (as per rfc2616) doesn't automatically make something RESTful, curious on this?

Comment: @Adam Conneg was just one example of how the WCF Web API has attempted to create a environment that gives you full access to the capabilities of HTTP. Not just for delivering HTML and JSON to web browsers.  ASP MVC is amazing for building web sites and it can be extended to do other stuff too.  WCF Web API was built from the ground up to provide a framework for building HTTP based services.  It is very suitable for building RESTful systems on top of.

Comment: I think my point may have been misinterpreted though - I'm very familiar with WCF, REST, and MVC - but by the requirements given above - the fact an interactive web app is clearly defined here with RESTful access on top of it to me MVC is the choice, thats all. Not that WCF couldnt do it-surely it could. Now you have services, and a separate web app. Based on the above I (personally) feel MVC. For content negotiation, the fact its available doesn't make it RESTful - see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/03/28/content-type-negotiation-and-rest-and-how-wcf-fits-in.aspx

Comment: To elaborate more so others don't have to read the whole article - different content types returned for the same source data (ex. pdf, word doc for the same resource) by stricter RESTful definition should have two separate URIs to identify them, as opposed to content negotiation done in the headers. Some obviously feel this isn't an issue, but by WCF having it and the ability to create RESTful services with WCF, doesn't mean it's automatically truly RESTful. Now that I've successfully beaten this horse beyond dead - the decision is up to the individual  - just my .08 cents : ) : )

Answer (score 1):

I would go with WCF, it is design for that purpose and if not all, most of the plumbing is done for you. With MVC to be used as restful service you will have re-implement few things to make it work like a real service.

Comment: Is it possible to play with WCF on a site I am testing on localhost with win XP? If it requires complex setup and windows server, then it will be somewhat difficult.

Comment: absolutely - our wcf services for our corporation are developed and tested on xp dev machines and we issue our own certs and test via ssl as well. the limitations come down to having IIS as a host for msmq services and a couple other things because of the version of iis but for the most part you'll have no issues