# Return ajax result to the new page using Asp.net mvc 2

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

**Please refer the code below**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
public ActionResult viewdetails(FormCollection form)
{
    String uname = Convert.ToString(form["uname"]);
    String mail = Convert.ToString(form["umail"]);
    //need to return the result value and url of viewdetails page      
}
```

**Ajax call to viewdetails Page**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'Post',
    url: '/Home/viewdetails',
    data: { uname: name, umail: email },
    success: function (result) {     
           //viewdetails page  redirect to the         
    }
});
```

I dont know how to redirect the result data to viewdetails page. Can u help me to recover from the problem

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

You'll want to research RESTful API development, this is much easier in MVC3 and above where you can use WebAPI.  However, there are Nuget packages that make this easier in MVC2.  Please review the below links and search google for `Restful Service "MVC2"`.

**Links to Help**

- http://forums.asp.net/t/1502967.aspx
- [Why use ASP.NET MVC 2 for REST services? Why not WCF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530880/why-use-asp-net-mvc-2-for-rest-services-why-not-wcf)
- http://beletsky.net/2011/01/implementation-of-rest-service-with.html